# Woocommerce link product visibility to day of the week

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, visibility

Does anyone know if it's possible to link a products' visibility in Woocommerce to specific days of the week? i.e. Monday, Products 1-4 visible, Tuesday, Products 5-10 etc, which would enable a restaurant menu to show only daily options that repeat each week?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Code

1. Copy the WooCommerce template file `content-product.php` to your theme's `woocommerce` directory
2. Change the area where it checks for visibility

   ### FROM

   ```
   // Ensure visibility
   if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() )
   return;
   ```

   ### TO

   ```
   // Ensure visibility
   // starting custom content
   $product_visible = check_for_product_allowed_days( $product );
   if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() || ! $product_visible )
   return;
   ```
3. Add the following to your functions.php file

```php
function check_for_product_allowed_days ( $product ) {

  $product_id  =  $product->id;
  $product_terms  =  get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
  // remove the strtolower if you capitalized your tag names
  $current_day  =  strtolower ( date ( 'l' ) );

  // $all_days value should be the name of the tag
  // that you want to be able to be ordered on all days
  $all_days  =  'all days';

  foreach ( $product_terms as $tag ) {
    if ( strtolower ( $tag->name )  ==  $current_day || $tag->name  ==  $all_days ) {
      $product_is_visible  =  true;
      break;
    }
    else {
      $product_is_visible  =  false;
    }
  }
  return $product_is_visible;
}
```

## WooCommerce Admin Setup

1. Add tags to all of your products

   - "All Days" or "all days" (just be sure to change the value of `$all_days` above to whatever you set it to be - monday, tuesday, wednesday

## Thinking

I couldn't find a method to break out of WooCommerce's loop and set the product visibility before hand so a template update was necessary

## Result

The results aren't updated to match with this code, but it shows in this example that there is more products than are displayed.

[image: example of code]

## [Solution Crossposted](http://wordpress.iamdez.com/2014/08/woocommerce-only-display-products-on-certain-days/)

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the code blocks... does it hate comments? does it not actually work right? I just spent 20 minutes futzing with it for no reason.